# Jenkins not cloning git repository to ${WORKSPACE}@script/ on multibranch project and aws codecommit

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins not cloning git repository to ${WORKSPACE}@script/ on multibranch project and aws codecommit.
Is it copy somewhere else?
I cannot see the repo neither in ${WORKSPACE} or ${WORKSPACE}@tmp/.

Comment: Are you using Beanstalk/EBCLI? If so, here's a related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751767/codecommit-error-elastic-beanstalk-aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explain in:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md
"checkout scm" should be used in Jenkinsfile.