# CodeCommit error Elastic Beanstalk (AWS)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codecommit

After running

```
pip install --upgrade awsebcli
```

I get the following error when trying to do

```
eb deploy
```

> Could not push code to the CodeCommit repository: ERROR: CommandError
>   - An error occurred while handling git command. Error code: 128 Error: fatal: 'codecommit-origin dev' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I can't figure out why that happened. It seems like the connection to the automatically generated repository codecommit-origin is not working anymore.

In the meantime, I am forced to do the following in order to update the code on Elastic Beanstalk:

> eb codesource local

But that's not a long-term solution as it deactivates the automatic CodeCommit (git push).

Do you have any idea how to solve that issue?

Comment: What do the debug logs (`eb deploy --debug` show)? Also, are you facing this problem with an older version of `awsebcli` as well?

Comment: I'm also curious to know whether the correct remote is actually listed in the `.git/config` file of your local repository.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Last line of the debug shows: lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/commonops.py", line 785, in create_codecommit_app_version raise e /// then it says "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists." but the AWS user has full permission to all CodeCommit repositories

Comment: And the correct remote is listed when I do: "git remote -v"

Comment: Okay, thanks. This looks like a bug, as also indicated in the other responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happened to me when I upgraded the last version of awsebcli 3.12.2, perhaps because it introduced the following ([changelog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli)):

> Fixed local-remote inconsistency observed after deployments using CodeCommit

I don't fully understand what is happening but I would suggest that you revert to the previous version with

```
pip install -Iv awsebcli==3.12.1
```

This has fixed my problem and I can deploy with CodeCommit again

Comment: Thank you! That at least allows me to keep working until the underlying issue is clear.

Comment: Thank you Matthieu!